# Using Debezium to connect to Secured Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, oauth, keycloak, debezium, sasl

I am trying to set up a Debezium Kafka Connect in a Kubernetes cluster, that connects with an external Kafka that is protected by a Keycloak, which functions as it OAUTH BEARER. In my Kubernetes deployment, I am able to give certain environment variables to apply to the producer. For example:

env:

```
    - name: BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
      value: "https://[REDACTED]:9095"

    - name: OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC
      value: connect-offsets

    - name: CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC
      value: connect-configs

    - name: STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC
      value: connect-status

    - name: CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM
      value: OAUTHBEARER

    - name: CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG
      value: org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required clientId=kafka clientSecret=[REDACTED];

    - name: CONNECT_SASL_OAUTHBEARER_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL
      value: "https://[REDACTED]/realms/kafka/protocol/openid-connect/token"

    - name: CONNECT_SASL_LOGIN_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS
      value: org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler

    - name: CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL
      value: SASL_SSL
```

This works, and the producers who creates the topics connect-offsets, connect-configs, connect-status all have proper ProducerConfigs, and the topics are created as intended. However, once I try to create a new Debezium connector, for example:

```
{
    "name": "postgres-db-connector-something-new",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "database.hostname": "postgresql",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "{{ $.Values.debezium.username }}",
        "database.password": "{{ .Values.debezium.password }}",
        "database.server.name": "output-management-db",
        "database.dbname": "output-management-db",
        "database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "OAUTHBEARER",
        "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required clientId=kafka clientSecret=[REDACTED];",
        "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "OAUTHBEARER",
        "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required clientId=kafka clientSecret=[REDACTED];",
        "table.whitelist": "public.audit",
        "topic.prefix": "output-management-db",
        "database.include.list": "public.audit",
        "publication.name": "dbz_publication",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "transforms": "dropBefore,dropSource",
        "transforms.dropBefore.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
        "transforms.dropBefore.blacklist": "before",
        "transforms.dropSource.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
        "transforms.dropSource.blacklist": "source"
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass the producer configs with the database.history.producer configurations, but it doesnt seem to take effect. When I check the logs of the KafkaConnect, it seems that the Producer it creates for actually pushing my messages from Postgres to Kafka does not have these important security settings set, and therefore fails connecting to the Kafka.

ProducerConfig:

```
acks = -1
auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [https://[REDACTED]:9095]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = connector-producer-postgres-db-connector-0
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = []
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
linger.ms = 0
max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
partitioner.class = null
partitioner.ignore.keys = false
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

The failure in the kafkaconnecter looks like this:

```
2023-08-01 12:41:13,682 INFO || [Producer clientId=connector-producer-postgres-db-connector-0]     Node -1 disconnected. [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
2023-08-01 12:41:13,682 INFO || [Producer clientId=connector-producer-postgres-db-connector-0] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 7 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 50ms, elapsed time since send: 50ms, request timeout: 30000ms) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
2023-08-01 12:41:13,682 WARN || [Producer clientId=connector-producer-postgres-db-connector-0] Bootstrap broker [REDACTED]:9095 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

I was expected that the Kafka Producer created by Debezium Kafka Connect would either have the same producer configs as the ones that created connect-offsets, connect-configs and connect-status topics. Otherwise, I would want some guidance in where I can add these configurations. Any help would be very much appreciated.